# vmware shared folders hgfs linux kernel 3.12 (ubuntu 14.04) not compiling

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, vmware-tools

Neither the vmware supplied hgfs module nor the hgfs module from the open-vm-tools
compiles on my machine running a 3.12 linux kernel.

The kernel was obviously configured with UIDGID_STRICT_TYPE_CHECKS and the module is
not using those types.

How can I get this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for the time beeing, until a proper fix has been released,
you can go, grab and try my

[modified hgfs module](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B66_i-BGnZVANHVDUmJ1Qmkxbk0/edit?pli=1).

It compiles here and works so far without issues.

Anyway, use is at your own risk, i just offer it here to spare some
of us the time digging into the code ...

replace the original `vmhgfs.tar` in

```
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/modules/source
```

with the modified one and run `vmware-config-tools.pl` which should now
successfully compile the module.

Comment: I did diffs on the patch, and it looks clean and safe -- just updating the name change of GID and UID types.  Tried it, and it works!  Thanks for empowering the new Ubuntu 14.04 release on VMs everywhere.

Comment: Hmm, well it compiles now, but I still don't see the share drives showing up in /mnt/hgfs...  More to do...

Comment: More info on this bug in the community:
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2357056#2357056
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/474260

Comment: VMWare Fusion 6.0.3 which was released yesterday solves this problem -- just update and reinstall the vmware tools.

Comment: I had this same issue.  I was running VMplayer 6.0.1 which used VMware-Tools-9.6.1.  When I upgraded to VMplayer 6.0.2 with VMware-Tools-9.6.2 the HGFS mounts worked fine again.  Give that a shot.